# ListView : how can I change a cell after a click?

Tags: android, listview, cell

I have a list view, containing different kinds of cells and I use an ArrayAdapter to do so.

```
private class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>
{   
    public MyAdapter(Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId, String[] objects)
    {
        super(context, resource, textViewResourceId, objects);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        View viewCE = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_cell, parent, false);
        ((TextView) viewCE.findViewById(R.id.txt_cell)).setText(adapter.getItem(position));
        view = viewCE;
        return view;
    }
}
```

`my_cell` contains an ImageView, and what I want to do is to change the image of this ImageView when the user clicks the cell.

I already added to my code a private class implementing `OnItemClickListener` with its method `onItemClick()` but then I've absolutely no idea of what to do...

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Put the complete code. I can't see any imageview in your adapter.

Comment: That's because when I create my view the image used is always the same, so I define it in the XML file, not in the adapter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in `onItemCLick` callback, the parameter `view` is exactly the view that contains your `imageView`, so you can find it by id then change it, sample codes are as below:

```
list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
        int position, long id) {
        ImageView image = ((ImageView) viewCE.findViewById(R.id.your_image_id));
        //do something by yourself
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to handle the click event on the ImageView differently than the onClick of list item, you can add a seperate onClickListener to the Imageview like below:

```
imageView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Change the image

        }

    });
```